# Calling up functions from another class in es6

Tags: javascript, class, oop, model-view-controller, ecmascript-6

My problem is very simple. Basically, I have a Controller and a View class. When I click a button, the controller tells the view to display a thing. Problem is, the Controller can't. Here's the code.

```js
class Controller {

    constructor(view) {
        view = new View();
      
        let button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            controller.doThing();
        });
    }
    
    doThing() {
        view.drawThing(5, 5);
    }

}

class View {
    
    constructor(controller) {
        let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        let pen = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        this.controller = Controller;
        this.drawThing = drawThing();
    }

    drawThing(x, y) {
        pen.beginPath();
        pen.moveTo(0, 0);
        pen.lineTo(x, y);
        pen.stroke();
    }

}
```

The result of which is an

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawThing' of undefined
at Controller.doThing (Controller.js:17)
at HTMLButtonElement.Controller.button.addEventListener (Controller.js:12)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `view` variable is scoped only to the constructor. You should use `this.view` instead:

```
class Controller {

    constructor(view) {
        this.view = new View();

        let button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            controller.doThing();
        });
    }

    doThing() {
        this.view.drawThing(5, 5);
    }

}
```

Comment: Alternatively, I'm guessing the `view` passed into the constructor is supposed to be some kind of inversion of control implementation. Could you show that option as well?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Do you mean that `view` should be assigned to `this.view`? I'm not sure what the OP wants to achieve with this code.

Comment: @Gothdo What you suggested works like a charm. Thanks a lot. Though, now it's telling me that it can't read the property of 'beginPath' in the view. Which is odd cause I don't recall having to use any third party libraries when they made us work with this code in class. Either way, thanks for the answer.